# can we pass props to another react router page without context and redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to pass data with props to another react router link page without redux and Context. Please tell me how to do this. Is this even possible if yes then please explain how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state or search in `to` prop of your link component

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

And then get it in your another component:

```
const { search, state } = useLocation();
```

Comment: raman thanks but i didnt understand as im a beginner .. can u please make and small program so that i can understand. will highly appreciate plzzz

Comment: if share with me what you already have I can help you with modifying your solution

Comment: actally i dont have.. i was trying to do but could'nt and now im doing with context api.. i should know with the props basics as well.. Please help